# ¿Cómo funciona Observable en ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic, observable, rxjs

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en ionic y para realizar peticiones http encontre un tutorial que utiliza el modelo observable, pero no entiendo como funciona, ni en que se ocupan `.do` `.map` y `.catch`, el código es el siguiente

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
/*
  Generated class for the MessageServiceProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class MessageServiceProvider {
    private url: string = "http://localhost/pruebas/json.php";
    respuesta: boolean = false;
    constructor(private http: Http) {
      console.log('Hello MessageServiceProvider Provider');
    }

   getMessages() {
      return this.http.get(this.url)
      .do(this.logResponse)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .do(this.logResponse)
      .catch(this.catchError)
   }

   private catchError(error: Response | any) {
      console.log(error);
      return Observable.throw(error.json().error || "Serve error");
   }
   private logResponse(res: Response) {
      console.log(res);
   }

   private extractData(res: Response) {
      this.respuesta = true;
      return res.json();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los Observables se utilizan cuando necesitas obtener datos de forma asíncrona, por ejemplo cuando necesitas obtener datos de un servidor.

En tu ejemplo haces una llamada a una url externa para obtener un json, al acabar la llamada utiliza la función do() para realizar la función logResponse() que se le pasa como argumento. Al acabar realiza la función map que aplica una función a todos los datos devueltos en la llamada (En este caso aplica la función extractData al objeto json devuelto).

La función catch() se activa solo si hay un error con la llamada y en este caso activaría la función catchError() la cual devuelve un error en forma de Observable.

Finalmente para obtener el resultado de res.json() (o el error) debes añadir un subscribe():

```js
getMessages() {
  return this.http.get(this.url)
    .do(this.logResponse)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .do(this.logResponse)
    .catch(this.catchError)
    .subscribe(
      resultado => this.messages = resultado, // En this.messages se guardará el 
                                              // resultado de extractData()
      error => console.log(error)
    )
}
```

Aquí tienes la guía por si necesitas más información acerca de los Observables: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html